# I'm very new to C# and have just been trying the basics, one of which is a warmer colder game

Tags: c#

I have gotten the very basics working with the following extremely basic code.

```
using System;

namespace Warmer_Colder_Game
{
    class RandomGenerator
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int guessNum;
            int guessNum2;
            int fillerInt;
            int stopNum = 1;
            System.Random random = new System.Random();
            int num = (random.Next(1, 1000));
            Console.WriteLine(num);
            Console.WriteLine("Guess A Number, 1 To 1000");
            string guess = Console.ReadLine();
            guessNum = Convert.ToInt32(guess);
            Console.WriteLine("Guess Another Number, 1 To 1000");
            string guess2 = Console.ReadLine();
            guessNum2 = Convert.ToInt32(guess2);


            do
            {
                if (stopNum == 0)
                {
                    guessNum = guessNum2;
                    string fillerNum = Console.ReadLine();
                    fillerInt = Convert.ToInt32(fillerNum);
                    guessNum2 = fillerInt;

                }
                if (guessNum2 == num)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Well Done, You've Burnt Yourself!");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (guessNum2 > guessNum && num > guessNum2 || guessNum2 < guessNum && num < guessNum2)
                    {
                         Console.WriteLine("Warmer");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Colder");
                    }
                }
                    
                

                stopNum = 0;
                



            } while (guessNum != num);


        }
    }
}
```

but whenever I go over the number you are trying to guess, lets say that number is 50 and my last guess was 25 and my new one is 51 it still says colder, and I can't find a work around as of right now, so some help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You should be comparing the absolute difference of each guess to the number.

Comment: One suggestion is to make your 1000 a constant, like `const int maxNum = 1000;`. Then make all the instances of "1000" (either as a number or a string: `$"Guess A Number, 1 To {maxNum}"`). Once you do that and get your code working the same as it is now, reduce the 1000 to 10 or 20 and debug your program.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to consider a scenario that `num` is between two guesses. Then use method [Math.Abs()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.abs?view=netcore-3.1) to determine the difference between them and num

```
if (Math.Abs(num - guessNum) > Math.Abs(num - guessNum2))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Warmer");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Colder");
}
```